# Summarize row values into columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

What I got:
A dataset that indicates the daily count of items sold in a store across a period of 100 days.
So, store 1 has 114 items sold on Day 1, 178 on Day2, and so on, till 143 items sold on day 100.
Also, the dataset has similar data for 1000 such stores. However, for some stores (like store 1000), count of sales is available only till Day 65.

```
| Store | Day |Count|
| -------- | -------------- |-------|
| 1    | 1            |114|
| 1   | 2            |178|
| ..    | ..            |..|
| 1   | 100           |143|
| 2    | 1            |197|
| 2   | 2            |159|
| ..    | ..            |..|
| 2   | 100           |39|
| 1000    | 1            |53|
| 1000   | 2            |132|
| ..    | ..            |..|
| 1000   | 65           |104|
```

What I require:
Divide the period of 100 days into 10 equal phases, viz Day 1-10, Day 11-20…Day 91-100.
For each store, find the median for each phase and report them in columns.
For stores that have full 100-day data such as 1 & 2, there would be 10 medians. (m_p1, …m_p10) 
While for the rest, there’d be less, like store 1000 will only have 7 median values.
The required table (with 1000 rows- 1 for each store) would look like this:

| Store | m_p1 | m_p2 | .. | m_p10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 | 157 | .. | 123 |
| 2 | 90 | 140 | .. | 121 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. | .. |
| 1000 | 45 | 102 | .. | NA |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a group of 10 days, calculate the `median` `Count` values and get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(group = ceiling(Day/10)) %>%
  group_by(Store, group) %>%
  summarise(Count = median(Count), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = Count, names_prefix = 'm_p')
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

#sample data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(store = rep(c(1,2), each = 100),
                 day = rep(1:100, 2),
                 Count = sample(80:100, 200, T))

str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    200 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ store: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ day  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ Count: int  94 98 93 82 89 97 90 84 99 93 ...

df %>%
  group_by(store, phase = (1 + ((day - 1) %/% 10))) %>%
  summarise(val = median(Count), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = phase, names_prefix = 'm_p', values_from = val)

#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#>   store  m_p1  m_p2  m_p3  m_p4  m_p5  m_p6  m_p7  m_p8  m_p9 m_p10
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1  93    87.5  91.5  87.5    93  92.5  91.5    90    91  93  
#> 2     2  87.5  91.5  92    90.5    91  90    88.5    90    91  94.5
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solutions too works equally well. Accepted Ronak's answer because I can choose only one, and he was the first to respond.