# Summarizing and tabulating unique values over rows from apply output in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame `dat` that has a variable for participant, `id` and made using

```
library(dplyr)

dat<-data.frame(
    id=c(2341, 5849, 9085, 8570, 9918),
    week_1=c("NULL", 0, 3, 5,0),
     week_4=c(0,0,2,0,3),
      week_8=c(0,1,1,4,1))

df <- dat %>% 
    mutate_all( ~replace(., lengths(.)==0, NA))
df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

which gives a data frame that looks like this:

```
    id week_1 week_4 week_8
1 2341   NULL      0      0
2 5849      0      0      1
3 9085      3      2      1
4 8570      5      0      4
5 9918      0      3      1
```

I use the following code to tabulate each of the unique values for each `id`

```
count_unique_values <- function(row) {
  # Use table to count unique values, including NAs
  tabulated_values <- table(as.character(row), useNA = "always")
  return(tabulated_values)
}

result <- apply(df, 1, count_unique_values); print(result)
```

which gives:

```
[[1]]

   0 2341 NULL <NA> 
   2    1    1    0 

[[2]]

   0    1 5849 <NA> 
   2    1    1    0 

[[3]]

   1    2    3 9085 <NA> 
   1    1    1    1    0 

[[4]]

   0    4    5 8570 <NA> 
   1    1    1    1    0 

[[5]]

   0    1    3 9918 <NA> 
   1    1    1    1    0
```

However, what i would like is a data frame formatted as below where for each id, the total number of zeros is in `r0`, the total number of 1s are in `r1`, etc, while dropping the NA values:

```
    id r0 r1 r2 r3 r4 r5
1 2341  2  0  0  0  0  0
2 5849  2  1  0  0  0  0
3 9085  0  1  1  1  0  0
4 8570  1  0  0  0  1  1
5 9918  1  1  0  1  0  0
```

I haven't been able to find out how to do this, and previous posts ([Summarizing unique values by group over multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69046569/summarizing-unique-values-by-group-over-multiple-columns), and
[Summarize row values into columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68859090/summarize-row-values-into-columns-in-r) )didn't seem to reveal the answer to me

Can someone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: in your toy data you have "NULL" maybe that should be NA (with no quotes), NULL in quotes will turn that column to a character variable and NULL with no quotes cannot be in a data.frame

Comment: Sorry, potentially I dont know the distinction. The data frame I am working with is the results of `dplyr::pivot_wider` which placed the NULL values there by default.

Comment: no problem here is a good article on the distinction: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2010/04/r-na-vs-null/

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)

dat |>
  mutate(across(-id, as.numeric)) |>
  mutate(r = list(table(unlist(pick(everything())))), .by = id,  .keep = "none") |>
  tidyr::unnest_wider(r, names_sep = "") |> 
  mutate(across(-id, ~ as.numeric(replace(., is.na(.), 0))))
```

**Output**

```
     id    r0    r1    r2    r3    r4    r5
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2341     2     0     0     0     0     0
2  5849     2     1     0     0     0     0
3  9085     0     1     1     1     0     0
4  8570     1     0     0     0     1     1
5  9918     1     1     0     1     0     0
```

**TL;DR:** You should probably handle the `NULL` values before your pivot since there is special functionality for `NULL` in R.

Based on your comments I think there are few things worth noting. `NULL` is a special value in R whereas `"NULL"` is just a character value. The former has special functionality around it, the latter is just a string to R:

```r
is.null(NULL)
[1] TRUE
length(NULL)
[1] 0

is.null("NULL")
[1] FALSE
length("NULL")
[1] 1
```

@Mike makes a good point in the comments. It cannot be a true `NULL` otherwise you would not have a data frame because if you try to `c`ombine `NULL` with other values you get:

```r
c(NULL, 0, 3, 5, 0)
[1] 0 3 5 0
```

This is not long enough (only 4 values when your data frame has 5 rows) to create a valid data frame.

If it is `"NULL"`, a character representation of the word NULL then the entire column is going to be character since columns in R are *atomic* (all one type) and there is a hierarchy for coercion from the least to most flexible type:

From `?c`:

> The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression.

```r
c("NULL", 0, 3, 5, 0)
[1] "NULL" "0"    "3"    "5"    "0"
```

It is for this reason that I have the line: `mutate(across(-id, as.numeric))` which forces everything to be numeric and throws a warning because `"NULL"` cannot be coerced to numeric and `NA` is returned instead, whereas `"3"` will be converted to `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `NULL` is actually an `NA`, and you want to record the number of `NA` values, you can use:

```r
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(starts_with("week"), names_to = "week", values_to = "r") %>%
    group_by(id, r) %>%
    summarize(n = n()) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = "id", values_from = n, names_from = r) %>% 
    mutate(across(-id, ~replace_na(., 0)))
```

that returns:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 8
     id    r0   rNA    r1    r4    r5    r2    r3
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  2341     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
2  5849     2     0     1     0     0     0     0
3  8570     1     0     0     1     1     0     0
4  9085     0     0     1     0     0     1     1
5  9918     1     0     1     0     0     0     1
```